# Stopping all working SparkContext?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm trying to test some Scala code on an IntelliJ worksheet. 
Even when all I write is this:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, SparkException}

val sc = new SparkContext()
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

I get:

```
WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:123)
```

Despite this being a completely fresh peace of code. I haven't ran anything since my computer booted.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: If you have `Interactive Mode` checked, each line you type re-executes the worksheet, maybe that's why you see this?

Comment: Interactive mode is deactivated.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can `stop()` the context at the end of the Worksheet, so that each time it runs, it leaves no running context:

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

try {
  // your code here... 
} finally {
  sc.stop()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help.. :/ It seems as `sc` is not the problem, but some other `SparkContext` activated by the `import` statements..